# Kubernetes StatefulSet error - serviceName environment variable doesn't exist

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, headless, statefulset

I'm supposed to make a StatefulSet with a Headless Service but when I make the Headless Service and create the StatefulSet only one pod gets made but with Error status and I get this error when trying to use kubectl log:

> serviceName environment variable doesn't exist! Fix your specification.

Here is my code:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: svc-hl-xyz
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: svc-hl-xyz
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: sts-xyz
spec:
  replicas: 3
  serviceName: "svc-hl-xyz"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: svc-hl-xyz
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: svc-hl-xyz
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ctr-sts-xyz
          image: XXX/XXX/XXX
          command: ["XXX", "XXX","XXX"]
```

My specification seems to follow the Kubernetes documentation for StatefulSet so I'm not sure why it doesn't work. All I can think of is that the command or the image I'm trying to use is causing this somehow.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you check statefulset via `kubectl describe statefulset sts-xyz` and check in the status section. Or maybe check the events via `kubectl get events` to check for abnormalities

Comment: Hi @chresse, thanks for your reply.

After kubectl describe statefulset/sts-xyz I get this as Pod status:
`Pods Status:        1 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed`

And kubectl get events gives me this:
`2m33s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate          statefulset/sts-xyz               create Pod sts-xyz-0 in StatefulSet sts-xyz successful`

Comment: kubectl describe pod on the sole pod (instead of 3) that get's made with Error status it says this:
`Warning  BackOff    68s (x25 over 6m10s)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container`

Comment: `Back-off restarting failed container` shows, that something is wrong with your pod/container and not the statefulset. I would check the (previous) logs from your pod `kubectl logs --previous <pod>`

Comment: I got this after trying that command @chresse
`unable to retrieve container logs for docker://abb48ca8650b574fd37cf1e49e322b759d63c5dfb8bd2d8391ea2614d807a42b`

So it does seem that it's the image I'm trying to use that's wrong. Or am I misunderstanding the message?

Comment: If there would be an issue with the image, there would be an "ImagePullBackoff" error. Maybe the logs simply got rotated and are not available anymore

Comment: If your container requires the `serviceName` environment variable to be set, you can set it in the pod spec: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/

Comment: I will try it with the pod spec @chresse. I didn't have any pod spec previously as I thought that StatefulSet would take care of that, like here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#components

Comment: Yes, but it seems your container requires it. Kubernetes does not know about the container requirements. I added an example spec in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74205718/1560953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container logs (`serviceName environment variable doesn't exist! Fix your specification.`) tell you that the `serviceName` environment variable is missing.

Add it to the container spec in your statefulset:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: sts-xyz
spec:
  replicas: 3
  serviceName: "svc-hl-xyz"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: svc-hl-xyz
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: svc-hl-xyz
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ctr-sts-xyz
          image: quay.io/myafk/interactive:stable
          command: ["interactive", "workloads","-t=first"]
          env:
           - name: serviceName
             value: svc-hl-xyz
```

More information about env variables on Pods can be found in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/)

Comment: You're very welcome. I should have read your initial question more carefully, so it would have been obvious faster :D

Comment: Yeah :D
I'm a bit embarrassed because I did try adding the env: at some point but didn't do it properly it seems...